# Downloading error "Could not retrieve the required disk image "

Tags: system-installation, wubi

When I try to download Ubuntu 12.04 using the Windows installer (Wubi) through a proxy server which requires proxy authentication, after I choose the Ubuntu installation size, username and password, when I click the Install button, I get this error:

```
An error occurred:
Could not retrieve the required disk image files
For more information, please see the log file:
c:\users\(myusername)\appdata\local\temp\wubi-12.04-rev266.log
```

The log file says: `proxy authentication error`

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: what version of windows? wubi is only supported in win 7 and lower. Not windows 8 yet.

Comment: Double check that you have the correct proxy password and that the proxy server does not have a rule to block the download.

Answer (score 0):

First try to extract the installation files from the .iso. Then put the .iso file into the folder where its contents were extracted. For example, put `ubuntu-12.04-desktop-i386.iso` (or whatever your `.iso` file is called) into a folder named ubuntu-12.04-desktop-i386 that was created by extracting the `.iso` itself. Then try installing again.

If you don't have the ability to extract the contents of an `.iso` file, you can do this in your Windows system with [7-Zip](http://www.7-zip.org/).

Comment: Extracting files from the ISO image isn't necessary (nor likely to be helpful): `wubi.exe` will recognize the ISO if put in the same directory as it (assuming the ISO has not been renamed and there are no other ISOs in the same folder and named like Ubuntu ISO images).

Answer (score 0):

Download the iso first and then extract it. This could be done by WinRar or 7Zip.

1. Now, disconnect to the internet to avoid redownload of the iso file.
   Then, open wubi.exe that include inside the iso that you has
   extracted.
2. Next, input all nessesary infomation and let the process run.
3. After the installation is complete. Boot to Ubuntu and setup your network connection
4. Then open Sofware Updater and update your Ubuntu.

Done, you are ready to use.